# I am creating a loop to find specific text and paste it in a newly created row

Tags: excel, vba

I am seeking to find Recommendations only in column A.  Once I find each Recommendation I want to insert a row below.  In that new row I want to paste the recommendation, but over one column (column B).

My code finds each Recommendation and creates a column and pastes the Recommendation text.  The problem is Recommendation is pasted where I want it, then each proceeding recommendation is pasted further up.

e.g. Recommendation 1 is offset(1,1)
Recommendation 2 is offset (-1,-1)
Recommendation 3 is offset (-2, -2).

I'm not sure why this is occurring.  I think my text is correct.

```
Sub Un_Adjust_Recommendations_EAFE()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

With Sheets("EAFE")
Set rRng = .Range("A1:A1000")
End With

Set rCell = rRng.Find(What:="Recommendation", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                 MatchCase:=True)
If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
Do
    rCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    rCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = rCell.Value
    rCell.Delete
    Set rCell = rRng.Find("Recommendation")
Loop Until rCell Is Nothing
End If

Sheets("Macro").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Rec 1 is (1,1) Red 2 is (-1,1), Red 3 (-2,1) Red 4 is (-3,1).  Not what I pasted above.

Comment: `rCell.Delete` - do you want to delete just that cell, or the entire row? Because you'll get a shift with deleting just the cell.

Comment: @BigBen That's the problem (thanks - I now know the line!) What I need to do is clear the contents of that cell, because otherwise the loop keeps finding the same Recommendation and continually pasting it one column over and one row below.

Comment: I'd propose using [`Range.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext). There are examples of how to use it here on SO. Or if you want to clear contents, `rCell.ClearContents`.

Comment: @BigBen.  I hard rCell.Clear before, and rCell.ClearContents makes everything perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeking to find Recommendations only in column A. Once I find each Recommendation I want to insert a row below. In that new row I want to paste the recommendation, but over one column (column B).

My code finds each Recommendation and creates a column and pastes the Recommendation text. The problem is Recommendation is pasted where I want it, then each proceeding recommendation is pasted further up.

e.g. Recommendation 1 is offset(1,1) Recommendation 2 is offset (-1,-1) Recommendation 3 is offset (-2, -2).

I'm not sure why this is occurring. I think my text is correct.

```
Sub Un_Adjust_Recommendations_EAFE()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

With Sheets("EAFE")
Set rRng = .Range("A1:A1000")
End With

Set rCell = rRng.Find(What:="Recommendation", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=True)
If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
Do
rCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
rCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = rCell.Value
rCell.ClearContents
Set rCell = rRng.Find("Recommendation")
Loop Until rCell Is Nothing
End If

Sheets("Macro").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe use something different than your question text - call out that `rCell.ClearContents` does the trick? Otherwise glad your problem is solved.

Comment: Yeah, just making it say rCell.ClearContents made the code work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to loop thru each cell from the last row up.

```
With Sheets("EAFE")
    For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Recommendation" Then

        'Or if "Recommendation" is part of a string, you can use
        'If .Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*Recommendation*" Then

            .Cells(i, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End With
```